# How to get refresh token in Linked In Oauth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

The below  documentation says

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/Refresh-Tokens-with-OAuth-2

> When exchanging Authorization Code for an Access Token, If Refresh Tokens are enabled,  the following fields will also be returned:
>
> refresh_token
>
> refresh_token_expires_in

But I don't see any proper documentation to enable refresh token, because I get access_token and expiry_in but not refresh token. So How to enable refresh token or any other param do I need to pass to get refresh token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top of that page states:

> LinkedIn has introduced Refresh Tokens with OAuth 2.0.  This feature
>   is currently available for a limited set of partners. It will be made
>   GA in the near future.

So I suppose you have to contact them and ask them to configure it for your app until they make it GA. That's how I read it at least.

The documentation is absolutely dreadful for a company that size! Good luck.